# Is it possible to move an internal SD card from a Samsung Galaxy S3 into another phone (Galaxy S2) to retrieve the information from the card?

Tags: sd, cellphone, mobile, card

Is it possible to move an internal SD card from a Samsung Galaxy S3 into another phone (Galaxy S2) to retrieve the information from the card, or is there any other way to access the information from the internal SD card?

Hello,

I have a Samsung Galaxy S3 and a Galaxy S2. They both have problems with the memboard but at least the S2 will still start up, although it's hardly possible to do anything at all with it.

I want to retrieve and access some information that I had written on the internal SD card of the Galaxy S3 phone. Is it possible to open it up, take out the internal SD card and move it to the S2 phone?

Or is there any other way to access the information from the internal SD card of the SG3 phone (it won't start up)?

Vesa

Comment: Is it really an SD card you're thinking of? They just pop into any card reader, no problems.

Comment: Try android.stackexchange, but I agree with @Xen2050

Comment: Internal SD card. It's soldered to the motherboard. it's just called internal SD card as far as I know, it's not the same as an external SD card that you can buy in any phone shop.

Answer (score 3):

Internal memory is soldered to the motherboard and is not physically a removable SD card.  So the short answer is no.

Obviously the IC could be desoldered if you have the equipment and skills, but it isn't something that you simply watch a video and then do.

Potentially you could connect the phone to a laptop via a USB cable and get the phone to accept ADB commands. The phone may need to be put into recovery mode. If that works then it would allow you to pull files from the internal memory to your computer. If it's photos then check your Google cloud storage, they may have automatically been backed up anyway.

Comment: What do you mean, I said the phone doesn't start up. How can I send an ADB command if it doesn't start in the first place? With regard to desoldering the IC card, that's also a part I would be interested in learning more about.

Comment: It may not appear to start up, but it may be starting up enough for ADB. The internal memory ic is in step 9 here: https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/Samsung+Galaxy+S+III+Teardown/9391

Comment: I have tried now. I was not able to connect using ADB shell command. It would be a good way of doing it. Any other way to connect over ADB?